# Purely html/javascript input character restriction

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to restrict the data inputted in a text field by the user by only allowing letters in it and must contain at LEAST 2 words(For name and surname) in this html line:

```
 <label name="CardHolderName">Card Holder Name</label> 
 <input type="Text" name="CardHolderName"required/><br>
```

I tried using the "RegExp"/RegularExpression in javascript but since I'm a beginner in coding and never learnt using the regexp I can't figure it out, anyone could suggest/help me please?Thanks.

P.S: If possible the code/function must be only in html and javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You need to listen keypress event in javascript

### HTML

```
 <label name="CardHolderName">Card Holder Name</label> 
 <input type="Text" id="cardHolderName" name="CardHolderName" required/><br>
```

### Javascript

```
  // we listen key up event of the keyboard 
 document.getElementById ('cardHolderName').keyup(function (e) {
         var t = e.currentTarget; // get the element
         var name = t.value; // get the value of the element 
         if(name.split(' ').length < 2) { // count elements splitted by an space
               // if it's less than two words, make stuff
         } 
 }) ;
```

Comment: This works, so it's not copy and paste and magic work. Attach the idea to your form submit function

Comment: I embedded the piece of code in the submit function that is written in the form tag which also includes a function to check future dates but can't find a way to fix it(I'm still learning coding)

Comment: So share your code, we haven't a crystal ball. This code works perfectly

Comment: I update your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/etLo66k9/1/ this is that you need to do in the beginning of the post. Learn how to ask in stackoverflow.com next time you ask a question.

Comment: Thanks the code works fine but I need the user to only input letters and it's allowing numbers, Is there a way to put this regexp /^[a-zA-Z]+$/ in the function to allow only upper/lowercase letters in the field?

Comment: Ye it's possible. Try it adding to the `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

If you define a 'word' as at least two characters, you could do something simple like this:

```
var is_valid = function(input) { 
    var min_length = 2, 
        space = ' ', 
        index_of_space = input.indexOf(space); 

    return
        index_of_space !== -1 
        && index_of_space >= min_length 
        && index_of_space < (input.length - min_length);
};
```

The condition being returned reads as "the input contains a space, and the space is at least the 3rd character, and the space is not within the last two characters".

The indexOf function only works on modern browsers, if you need to support older browsers (IE 8 and below), there is a polyfill available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: I'm sorry if I ask this but I'm a beginner in coding and don't really understand but I put this code in the script tag and modified the html to <input type="Text" id="cardHolderName" name="CardHolderName" onforminput="function(input)" required/><br> but it isn't working.